# Redirecting Input and Output from IDLE shell into a new PyQt GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

Okay so I am new and still learning all the time and I am trying to wire up a GUI for my code. My code works perfectly in Python IDLE shell and as of so far, works perfectly in my GUI I have created. I have yet to learn 
how to multithread processes, I would like multithread all of my functions and redirect output and input from IDLE shell to the three text boxes in my GUI. As of so far, I am pressing my buttons and they work as intended, 
all input and output from after pressing a button is in the IDLE shell and my next step is to feed input and output to my text boxes in my GUI, so that my migration from IDLE shell to my GUI is complete and so that my GUI 
can 'standalone' independent from the IDLE shell of course. The three text boxes include, 1. for text input, 2.for listing results. and 3. for actively displaying my update features. The program I am making is a file search 
method by way of indexing, it works fine in the shell and i am migrating to my GUI. In the shell, when I update say Text files, 
the code runs in and out of directories making a list of all text files on the system and saving them in a file, it also does this for video, audio, executable and image files. When the update is executed, files with the 
appropriate file extensions for the particular update are displayed in real time in the IDLE shell, streaming down the IDLE shell very fast, this is hopefully the job for text box three, these results will be displayed in 
text box three as they are found, for feedback purposes. Text box 1 is user input, the file name to search for, when in IDLE shell, the name entered is searched for in the lists made by my update feature, instead of 
scanning the system every time. The result/(s) is then displayed in the shell, this works perfectly and can be opened/played/executed if the user wishes by appending the found path+filename to the appropriate module. This 
brings me to text box 2, where in the shell, file results from a search are displayed where they will hopefully now be migrated to text box 2, which is where search results will be displayed from now on.
I am asking for examples how i my case I would achieve this migration from shell to GUI. I will post my code as is and perhaps someone with much more experience can provide some examples on how to re-wire this.
Thank you in advance for any help, Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

When a user runs code with IDLE, output sent to stdout, either with sys.stdout.write or print() with file left as sys.stdout, appears in the tk(inter) Text widget of IDLE's Shell because IDLE replaces the default sys.stdout object with with an object that sends sends strings to the Text widget.  Since this involves usually inter-process communication, the code will probably not of must use to you.

What might help is the following: Find in Files (grep) puts found lines in an OutputWindow with a write method that accepts a string and returns the number of characters written.  Here is the 3.x version.

```
def write(self, s, tags=(), mark="insert"):
    if isinstance(s, (bytes, bytes)):  # convert to string if necessary
        s = s.decode(IOBinding.encoding, "replace")
    self.text.insert(mark, s, tags)  # insert into widget
    self.text.see(mark)  # make insertion visible
    self.text.update()  # update widget
    return len(s)  # return # chars written
```

I presume you can rewrite this for (py)qt's text widget.  The alternative is to use the widget methods directly.